# Node js mongoose populate limit

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, pagination

I have two schema say city and blogs. I want to create a blog page with pagination. So I am populating blogs with reference to city name. Say if I dont have a blog for a city then it should not be returned. Here is my query to get the blogs.

```
City.find().skip(req.params.pageIndex*2).limit(2).sort('-created').populate('articles').exec(function(err, cities) {

res.jsonp(cities)

}
```

If I use the above query. I get the cities with no blogs as well. So it results in an empty row in the view. I don't want that to happen. How to limit the populated field and not return the city without blogs. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 33):

```
City.find({}).populate({
    path:'Articles',
    options: {
        limit: 2,
        sort: { created: -1},
        skip: req.params.pageIndex*2

    }
}).exec(function (err, cities) {
    if (err) return handleError(res, err);
    return res.status(200).json(cities);
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Instead of using

```
{options:{limit:2}}
```

Use like

```
{perDocumentLimit:2}
```

Its works for me